Drawning an image but with the eyes removed and part of the face skeleton
Assalamu alaykum, Would a picture of an animal fall under the category of image, if the eyes are removed and part of the face around the eyes is Skeletal? I vaguely remember that in  Al-Iqna' li-Talib al-Intifa' by Ibn al-Hajjawi, Al-Rawd al-Murbi' by Al-Buhuti and Muntaha al-Iradat by Ibn al-Najjar they mention something along the lines of, if the eyes are removed then it is no longer a complete image and therefore permissible... any info would be great, barakallahu feekum.
